# node js : Not able to run socket.io

Tags: node.js

I am having an issue to run app in node js. App is running smoothly but I am getting this error

```
https://172.16.4.213:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N4GTAbU
```

Here is my complete code

```
var express = require('express.io')

var fs = require('fs')
var https = require('https')
var app = express()
var PORT = 3000;
app.https().io();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index.ejs');
})

https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')
}, app)
.listen(PORT,"172.16.4.213")

require('socket.io').listen(PORT,"172.16.4.213")


app.io.route('signal', function(req) {
    req.io.join(req.data)
    app.io.room(req.data).broadcast('signal', {
        user_type: req.data.user_type,
        user_name: req.data.user_name,
        user_data: req.data.user_data,
        command: req.data.command
    })
})
```

It's a video call app 1to1 peer

Comment: This `https://172.16.4.213:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N4GTAbU` is not an error.  That's how socket.io connections start.  If there is an actual error, then show us the actual error.

Comment: `https://172.16.4.213:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N4GTAbU` if you have this error in browser console then its means that socket.io at this url not responding , according to your settings your socket url is same your app url not with socket.io